# connect flutter and website through one login form

Tags: flutter, authentication, flutter-web

I've been working on app that use Firebase_Auth to allow user to login or signing but now I need to connect user to a website at the same time he login or signing to the app through verification maybe, so the user don't need to login and enter his password and email again also allowed to download files or do anything in website but i don't actually know how to do that, do I need to write js code inside website code or there is a plugin in flutter that can do that like [this plugin in flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_web_auth)

thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Flutter is good for single page websites, but not a whole website package yet. You've to use JS and Firebase JS scripts/npm to integrate Firebase into your website.